# How to reverse query in a 1:N relationship in JDO datanucleus?

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I am working on JDO datanucleus,and I have a list of Objects inside other object as shown below.

User.java

```
    public class User {
         @Persistent(primaryKey = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
         long id;
        -----
        -----
          @Persistent(persistenceModifier = PersistenceModifier.PERSISTENT, defaultFetchGroup = "true", mappedBy="user")
         @Join 
         List<Category> categorylist;
       -------
    }
```

Category.java

```
public class Category {
        @Persistent(primaryKey = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
    private long id;
------
}
```

Now as I read on datanucleus site, it is bidirectional relation. Now How do I make a query to access all Users with a having a particular category?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You read that is "bidirectional" ? Where ? Bidirectional means you have "User" field in Category, and you don't. So no, its unidirectional, and the mappedBy is wrong.

Comment: I got my mistake, there must be reference in Category class which can direct to User. So Now basically I need M:N relationship because in my code, many User might fall into one Category. Thanks for quick reply. Will read about M:N relations in Datanucleus. Thanks again for reply and saving my time :)